# Buildsolution fails with the token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I've just recently set up a new machine and when I build my IoT Edge solutions on the new machine I get the following error

I believe it's choosing the work agent but now sure how to check it.

```
docker build  --rm -f "c:\Code\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagAverager\Dockerfile.amd64.debug" -t enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagaverager:0.0.2-amd64.debug "c:\Code\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagAverager" && docker build  --rm -f "c:\Code\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagProcesser\Dockerfile.amd64.debug" -t enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagprocesser:0.0.1-amd64.debug "c:\Code\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagProcesser"
At line:1 char:243
+ ... ject\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagAverager" && docker  ...
+                                                                ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

On may old machine in which it works fine

```
docker build  --rm -f "d:\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagAverager\Dockerfile.amd64.debug" -t enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagaverager:0.0.2-amd64.debug "d:\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagAverager" ; if ($?) { docker push enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagaverager:0.0.2-amd64.debug } if ($?) { docker build  --rm -f "d:\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagProcesser\Dockerfile.amd64.debug" -t enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagprocesser:0.0.1-amd64.debug "d:\Project\Enerlytics - Edge\EnerlyticsEdge\modules\TagProcesser" } if ($?) { docker push enerlytics.azurecr.io/tagprocesser:0.0.1-amd64.debug }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the solution but the error went after updated to .netcore2.2, but I don't believe is the correct solution